# .removeClass() not working in IE and FireFox

Tags: jquery, html, css

If a click is detected on the first div it will remove a class on the second div so that it's contents will be visible.

HTML

```
<div id="pp-post-{post_id}" class="pp-post"></div>

<div id="pp-post-container-{post_id}" class="pp-post-container element-invisible"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
  $('.pp-post-item').on('click', function() {
    let postFullId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    let postNumId = postFullId.slice(13);
    $('.pp-post-container').not('.element-invisible').addClass('element-invisible');
    $('#pp-post-container-' + postNumId).removeClass('element-invisible');
  });
```

This all works great in Chrome. But it doesn't work in IE, FireFox, or Chrome and not sure why.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: *"This all works great in **Chrome**. But it doesn't work in IE, FireFox, or **Chrome** and not sure why."* Say what?

Comment: ~~Do you have the html5 doctype at the top? `<!doctype html>`~~ Nevermind, it wasn't clear that `{post_id}` was just a placeholder and not the actual id

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: `.pp-post-item` doesn't match any element at all in your quoted HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.pp-post-item` doesn't match any element at all in your quoted HTML. I assume you want `.pp-post` and `.slice(8)` instead of `.slice(13)`. If you make those changes, it works on Chrome, Firefox, and IE11:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.pp-post').on('click', function() {
    let postFullId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    let postNumId = postFullId.slice(8);
    $('.pp-post-container').not('.element-invisible').addClass('element-invisible');
    $('#pp-post-container-' + postNumId).removeClass('element-invisible');
  });
});
```

```css
.element-invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="pp-post-1" class="pp-post">div 1</div>
<div id="pp-post-container-1" class="pp-post-container element-invisible">container 1</div>

<div id="pp-post-2" class="pp-post">div 2</div>
<div id="pp-post-container-2" class="pp-post-container element-invisible">container 2</div>

<div id="pp-post-3" class="pp-post">div 3</div>
<div id="pp-post-container-3" class="pp-post-container element-invisible">container 3</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I forgot to add that <div> in there:      <div id="pp-post-item-{post_id}" class="pp-post-item">
              {thumbnail}
              {title}
             <p class="pp-arrow-down"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
 </div>

Comment: Ok that works, but for some reason this doesn't work for me in IE: $('.pp-post-container').not('.element-invisible').addClass('element-invisible');

I'm gonna have to dive deeper into your example and compare.